# How to connect to a remote database server using Python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, linux, database, server

I am trying to connect to a remote database server that is installed on CentOS 7 in VMware from windows using python, but I am unable to connect to it. I am using mysql.connector to access the database.Please help me solve the problem.

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="192.168.136.129", user="root", passwd="root", database="test", port=3306)
mycr = mydb.cursor()
mycr.execute("CREATE TABLE cat (name VARCHAR(25));")
```

Comment: any error message?

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.136.129 from your local box successfully? Also, is VMWare bridging into your network properly?

Comment: ok i'll try. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Both virtual machine and the windows are pinging each other successfully. And also VMWare is  bridging into my network."mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.136.129:3306' (10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)
". This is the error i'am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use root user there might be some permission issue.
Try creating a new user and access it.

Comment: I will try when i get home. Thanks

Comment: I think i should open an ssh tunnel to the server. You guys think it will work. Need help faster ASAP.